# Add data.csv and main.py to a single exe using auto-py-to-exe

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, exe

I'm trying to save user input to a file and retrieve data. It works okay when running the main.py from command-prompt. But when I've converted main.py and user_data.csv into a single .exe file using auto-py-to-exe, no data is saved and retrieved. The program runs perfectly okay.
Here are some lines:

To read Data:

```
data_file = resource_path('./user_data.csv')
if os.path.exists(data_file):
    userdatas = open(data_file, 'r').read().split("\n")
    userdatas.remove(userdatas[0])
    userdatas.remove(userdatas[int(len(userdatas)-1)])

for userdata in userdatas:
    sls.append(userdata.split(",")[0])
    usernames.append(userdata.split(",")[2])
    passwords.append(userdata.split(",")[3])
    company_Names.append(userdata.split(",")[1])
```

To get user input:

```
def usercred():
    username = input('Enter E-mail ID: ')
    res_list = [i for i in range(len(usernames)) if usernames[i] == username]
    if len(res_list)>0:
        password = passwords[res_list[0]]
    else:
        password = input('Enter Password: ')
        company_Name = input("Company Name: ")

        sls.append(len(sls)+1)
        usernames.append(username)
        passwords.append(password)
        company_Names.append(company_Name)
        writedata()
    return res_list,username,password,company_Name
```

To write data:

```
def writedata():
    records = []
    #Initializing writer
    user_data = open(data_file, 'w', buffering=1, encoding='utf8')
    writer = csv.writer(user_data, lineterminator = '\n')
    # Add titles
    titles = ['Sl', 'Name', 'E-mail', 'Password']
    # Write table titles
    writer.writerow(titles)
    # Write Records
    for i in range(len(usernames)):
        records.extend([i+1,company_Names[i],usernames[i],passwords[i]])

        writer.writerow(records)
        records = []
```

I've used auto-py-to-exe. In the project, I've used a webdriver. I just used --add-binary for the webdriver, and it works perfectly. Code is here:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(resource_path('./chromedriver.exe'))
```

When I --add-data for the user_data.csv, it just didn't serve its purpose. The program runs ok here too. "One File" and "console-based" were used.

What to do with the code or how to convert .py to .exe so that the thing works.

Another quick Q: is there any way to close the console after finishing the program by pressing any key or automatically?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: So you are hoping to embed `user_data.csv` inside the EXE and have the script update the contents of it? i.e. modify the EXE

Comment: Not necessary. It should work when it's not embedded, and it's not working.

Comment: I suggest you instead use `with open(data_file, 'w', buffering=1, encoding='utf8') as user_data:` to ensure the file is correctly closed at the end (indent all the code under it)

Comment: Not working. `with open(.....)` and at the end I tried adding `user_data.close()` also. Still not working. Is there any other way to do the same thing? It's not necessary to save the data in a csv file. I just need to store and retrieve data.

Comment: I suggest you add lots of print statements to determine what is not working. I am assuming you see no error messages and the programs just finishes?

Comment: I think I've solved the problem. I've used `base_path = pathlib.Path().resolve()` instead of `base_path = os.path.dirname(__file__)` in the `resource_path` function. Defined a new function with that only for the data file. Reason was exe file was looking for data file here: `\\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI137322\./user_data.csv`. Thank you for your support!